# javascript change onblur value

Tags: javascript

I have 2 selections and a textbox. I want to change the onBlur value of the textbox when i select one of the selections. Here is my code:

```
function changeBlurValue(){

    $selection = document.getElementById("searchtype") 
    $onblurvalue= document.getElementById("searchbox") 
    if ($selection.value="location"){
    $onblurvalue.value="Enter a location name";
    };
}
```

//html

```
<select name= "searchtype" id="searchtype" onclick="changeBlurValue()">
               <option value="gymname">Gym Name 
               <option value="location">Location
             </select><br><br>
<input name="searchterm" type="text" size="39" style="color:#888;" id="searchbox"
    value="Enter a gym name" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />
```

The problem is that the selection is permanent at "Location" and I can't change it to "Gym Name"

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
 if ($selection.value="location"){
```

You should change it to

```
 if ($selection.value=="location"){
```

because you are making a comparision.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using `onChange` instead of `onClick` for your select.

```
<select name= "searchtype" id="searchtype" onchange="changeBlurValue()">
```

Also close your `<option>` tags, as such:

```
<select name= "searchtype" id="searchtype" onchange="changeBlurValue()">
  <option value="gymname">Gym Name</option>
  <option value="location">Location</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! i am able to do so for once but after that, it will stuck at "location" forever...

Comment: It would help a lot if you make a JSFiddle